# PyQt5 multiple buttons and 1 function to change button text

Tags: function, button, pyqt5

I have an application with multiple buttons
When pressed a button, the text on the pressed button has to be changed.
This can be done with a separate function for each button, but I want to use 1 function to keep the code short.

Code so far:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys


class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 700, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle("Tic Tac Toe")
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(50)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.btn1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 50, 93, 91))
        self.btn1.setFont(font)
        self.btn1.setObjectName("btn1")
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(lambda:self.function("btn1"))
        self.btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.btn2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 50, 93, 91))
        self.btn2.setFont(font)
        self.btn2.setText("")
        self.btn2.setObjectName("btn2")
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(lambda:self.function("btn2"))

        font2 = QtGui.QFont()
        font2.setPointSize(16)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 50, 201, 51))
        self.label.setFont(font2)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

    def function(self, btnnmbr):
        self.label.setText("knop " + btnnmbr)
        #self.btn1.setText("X")    
        

     


# Mainloop
def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

window()
```

Any idea how to change the text of the clicked instance of a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 700, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle("Tic Tac Toe")
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        
        self.btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.btn1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 50, 93, 91))
        self.btn1.setFont(font)
        self.btn1.setObjectName("btn1")
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(lambda ch, btn=self.btn1: self.function(btn))  # +
        
        self.btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.btn2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 50, 93, 91))
        self.btn2.setFont(font)
        self.btn2.setText("")
        self.btn2.setObjectName("btn2")
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(lambda ch, btn=self.btn2: self.function(btn))  # +

        font2 = QtGui.QFont()
        font2.setPointSize(16)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 50, 201, 51))
        self.label.setFont(font2)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

    def function(self, btn):                                                     # + btn
        self.label.setText(f"knop {btn.objectName()}")                           # +
        btn.setText(btn.objectName())                                            # +++
        #self.btn1.setText("X")    
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]